# Swift - IOS : How to measure height and width of item from within layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionviewcell with multiple textfields, pictures and labels together. The data is dynamically added, which can have shorter or longer labels and pictures making each cell of collectionview having different height and width. I want to measure the width and height of my collectionviewcell programatically to do multiple things, amongst them is also setting number of columns according to width and height of my cell as per different orientation.
Any ideas how can a width and height be measured?
The layout is drawn on main storyboard without any extra xib. I'll highly appreciate the response

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use AutoLayout to setup UI.And set collectionview layout as following code:

```swift
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

You don't need to measure the size of cell, the system will do all.

If you want to measure by yourself, you'd better cache size of cell for better performance.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Flowlayout brings with it, its own complexisites. The allignment is not corrected, since it is always centerd oriented. I don't want multicolumns if number of items is let say 2, which can sufficiently fits on screen without needing multiple columns. So I have no other option measuring size of items and then decide what to do? Do you know, how to measure width and height of cellitem once the data is loaded  ?

Comment: @jahnze It's hard to explain clearly here. I suggest you google "UICollectionView waterfall layout" or "UICollectionView custom layout", I think you will find all you want.

Comment: There ain‘t any example of measuring dynamic width and height. That‘s what actually I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't have to know your view's dimensions (sometimes, but rarely). For instance, I've written a view that mimics the behavior and look of Apple HealthKit's move/exercise/stand rings, and extended it so it can display as many rings as you want, and display a percentage value (e.g. "80%") of the innermost ring or, if you prefer, use a closure to include another subview inside the innermost ring. With all of this, I didn't need to know the view's dimensions.

The trick to it is really to invert your thinking a bit. Try to push configuration into the view, and make your view adaptable.

You mentioned that alignment is challenging; yes, but once you really get the hang of it, it's powerful. I'd recommend this reference on how to make the best use of alignment guides, it's an excellent explanation: https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/

But if all else fails and you are absolutely determined to use the view's dimensions, take a look at `GeometryReader`:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("Left")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.33)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        Text("Right")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.67)
            .background(Color.orange)
    }
}
.frame(height: 50)
```

Check out Hacking with Swift for a more in-depth explanation: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-provide-relative-sizes-using-geometryreader

Be careful with `GeometryReader` though. Look at using it in a `.background()` or `.overlay()` to avoid altering your view. The catch-22 with it is that in order to figure out your view's dimensions, `GeometryReader` creates a view that fills all available space... and this actually can affect the layout of your view. But if you put it in an overlay, you can avoid the problem. Using it tends to be more work than just figuring out how to do the layout without needing to know dimensions. That's how SwiftUI is designed to work.

Comment: I appreciate your response. As far as I have understood GeometryReader, I want to achieve exactly the opposite. I want layout manager to layout the contentview according to its content. Once it is done, determine the dimensions and make changes to layout if necessary e.g. no of columns. However geometryread is providing me frame on which I can place element variably.